# How can I modify my directive's templateURL based on values within its controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have the following AngularJS directive and its controller.

Instead of entering the HTML right into the directive's `template` field, I would like to set the `templateURL` based on values of integers `aB` and `aC` in the associated controller.

If `aB + ac >= 10`, I want it to use `foo.html` otherwise I want it to use `bar.html`. How can I do that?

```
myApp.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: {
        myObject: '='
      },
      controller: 'myDirectiveCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'myDrCtrl',
      bindToController: true,
      template: 'aB={{myDrCtrl.myObject.aB}} aC={{myDrCtrl.myObject.aC}}'

    };
  }
);

myApp.controller('myDirectiveCtrl', function($scope){
    var self = this;
    $scope.$watch(function() {return self.myObject}, function (objVal) {
        console.log("watch fired");
        console.log('objVal.aB = ', objVal.aB);
        console.log('objVal.aC = ', objVal.aC);
    },true);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ngInclude instead:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: {
        myObject: '='
      },
      controller: 'myDirectiveCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'myDrCtrl',
      bindToController: true,
      template: '<div ng-include="myObject.currentPath"></div>'

    };
  }
);

myApp.controller('myDirectiveCtrl', function($scope){
    var self = this;
    $scope.$watch(function() {return self.myObject}, function (objVal) {
         objVal.currentPath = 'bar.html';
         if(objVal.aB + objVal.aC >= 10){
             objVal.currentPath = 'foo.html';
         }
    },true);
});
```

Comment: and then in the HTML files, I access the values of aB and aC like this: `aB: {{myDrCtrl. myObject.aB}} aC is: {{myDrCtrl. myObject.aC}}`. Is there a cleaner way to access them from there?

Answer (score 2):

`template`/`templateUrl` option of directive gets evaluated before directive scope gets created. So basically you can't get scope variable over there inside `templateUrl` function.

But yes you could solve this problem by using `ng-include` directive there, with expression will create a URL dynamically based on scope variable values.

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: {
        myObject: '='
      },
      controller: 'myDirectiveCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'myDrCtrl',
      bindToController: true,
      template: '<ng-include src="(aB + ac >= 10) ? \'foo.html\': \'bar.html\'"></ng-include>'
    };
  }
);
```